# What collection interface to choose?

Tags: c#, .net

What collection interface is preferred for the system? By system I mean Repositories, Services, etc. So I need to choose IEnumerable, ICollection, IList or may be even List.

I guess theoretically it would be better to use IEnumerable. But it is less convenient to use: for example, I have to use GetElementAt method instead of indexer.

My current choice is IList but I doubt about this decision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It really comes down to what type of access you want to allow for consumers of your Repositories, Services, etc.

If you only intend consumers to read through the collection, use `IEnumerable<T>` (no write-type methods are available).

If you'd like consumers to add directly to the collection, then the methods in `ICollection<T>` will give them that.

In general, I try to expose collections as `IEnumerable<T>` as often as I can. When users want to add something to the collection, they have to call a separate method rather than directly writing to the collection itself. It gives you a chance to validate the input, perform other checks, etc.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to allow indexer access, you should use `IList<T>`.  The general rule is to use the least-specific type possible that still meets all the usage requirements.  And in your case, that sounds like a list.  (and of course, `IList<T>` is less specific than `List<T>`)